# User input is restricted to odd no? Whats wrong with code?

Tags: c, scanf

I need help regarding the below code.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
       #include<ctype.h>
    int No_Of_Students()
    {
       int n;
       printf("\nEnter the number of students : ");
       scanf("%d",&n);
       return n;
    }
    void Grading(int n)
    {
        int m70=0,m50=0;
        printf("\nEnter the Grade of %d students one by one :\n ",n);
        while(n>0)
        {
            if(Grade_input())
            m70++;
            else
            m50++;

            n--;
        }

        display(m70,m50);
    }
    int Grade_input()
    {
        char Grade;
        Grade=getchar();
        Grade=toupper(Grade);
        if(Grade=='S'|| Grade=='A'||Grade=='B')
            return 1;
        else
        if(Grade=='E'||Grade=='F')
            return 0;
    }
    void display(int s,int f)
    {
        printf("\n%d no of students have scored more than 70% ",s);
        printf("\n%d no of students have scored less than 50% ",f);
    }
    int main()
    {
        int N;
        N=No_Of_Students();
        Grading(N);
        return 0;

    }
```

why doesn't it takes specified inputs? like,if input is 3, it only takes one input and returns immediately.

Is there any mistakes in it?

Comment: Why don't you just put a breakpoint at the line following the `scanf("%d",&n)` line, run the program, enter 3 and see whether or not this input is accepted? Spoiler: it is. Conclusion: This is not where your problem is.

Comment: You must "escape" the `%` signs in the formatting strings, as `50%%` and `70%%` to prevent the `printf` function expecting them to be format specifiers.

Comment: If you follow up the compiler warnings you should find that not all the functions have a "prototype", and that in `Grade_input()` *not all control paths return a value*. What value would it return if `Grade=='C'` ? Please fix all these warnings and then see how the code behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it only takes one input because it will  only go to `int No_Of_Students()`
and function `Grading(N)` will not work because you have called function in it before declaring them and then add one `getchar()` here:

`char Grade;
getchar();
Grade=getchar();`
(instead of Grade you took \n as input)

here is changed form of your code:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>



int No_Of_Students()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nEnter the number of students : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    return n;
}
int Grade_input()
{
    char Grade;
    getchar();
    Grade = getchar();
    Grade = toupper(Grade);
    if (Grade == 'S' || Grade == 'A' || Grade == 'B')
        return 1;
    else
        if (Grade == 'E' || Grade == 'F')
            return 0;
}
void display(int s, int f)
{
    printf("\n%d no of students have scored more than 70% ", s);
    printf("\n%d no of students have scored less than 50% ", f);
}
void Grading(int n)
{
    int m70 = 0, m50 = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the Grade of %d students one by one :\n ", n);
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if (Grade_input())
            m70++;
        else
            m50++;

        n--;
    }

    display(m70, m50);
}


int main()
{
    int N;
    N = No_Of_Students();
    Grading(N);
    return 0;

}
```

I rewrote your code and changed function places.

you can also call all of functions before main and then declare them after main.

Answer (score 0):

Add function prototypes in your code before all functions

```
 int No_Of_Students();
 void Grading(int n);
 int Grade_input();
 void display(int s,int f);
```

And add this loop before `Grade=getchar();` in `Grade_input()` function

```
while((ch=getchar())!='\n'&&ch!=EOF);
```

This is to flush the stdin and In `int Grade_input()` function what happens if user enters value other than `S,A,B,E,F`. So write the code for re asking grade if user enter other values.

See this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int No_Of_Students();
void Grading(int n);
int Grade_input();
void display(int s,int f);


int main()
{
        int N;
        N=No_Of_Students();
        Grading(N);
        return 0;
}

int No_Of_Students()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nEnter the number of students : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    return n;
}
void Grading(int n)
{
        int m70=0,m50=0;
        printf("\nEnter the Grade of %d students one by one :\n",n);
        while(n>0)
        {
            if(Grade_input())
            m70++;
            else
            m50++;

            n--;
        }

        display(m70,m50);
}
int Grade_input()
{
        char Grade,ch;
        do
        {
            while((ch=getchar())!='\n'&&ch!=EOF);
            Grade=getchar();
            Grade=toupper(Grade);
            if(Grade=='S'|| Grade=='A'||Grade=='B')
                return 1;
            else if(Grade=='E'||Grade=='F')
                return 0;

            printf("NO GRADE:%c\n",Grade);
        }while(Grade!='S'&&Grade!='A'&&Grade!='B'&&Grade!='E'&&Grade!='F');

}
void display(int s,int f)
{
        printf("\n%d no of students have scored more than 70% ",s);
        printf("\n%d no of students have scored less than 50% ",f);
}
```